# Meteorjs: How can I use variables which are defined in template events inside my template helpers?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Here's my events code:

```
    Template.pricing_report.events({
        'click #btn_report_filter': function(){

        from_date = $("#datepicker1").val();
        to_date = $("#datepicker2").val();


        date_n = new Date(from_date);
        from_iso = date_n.toISOString();

        date_o = new Date(to_date);
        to_iso = date_o.toISOString();
    }

});
```

I want to use the variables `from_iso` and `to_iso` in my helpers which is given below:

```
Template.pricing_report.helpers({

    'preportdata':function(){
        return price.find();
},

    'preportdata_test':function(){
        return price.find({
            date: {
                $gte: from_iso,
                $lt:  to_iso
            }
        });
}
```

As you can see, I have used my `from_iso` and `to_iso` inside the find function but I am unable to get the value to the helper function.

I also tried to use `console.log`(from_iso) inside my helper function but its also displaying nothing.

So, how can I use these variables?

Answer (score 2):

You should read about ReactiveVar: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg

Quick example:

```
Template.pricing_report.onCreated(function () {
    this.date_n = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.pricing_report.events({
    'click #btn_report_filter': function (e, tmpl) {

        tmpl.date_n.set(new Date(from_date)); 

    }
});

Template.pricing_report.helpers({
    'helperName':function () {
        var tmpl = Template.instance();
        return tmpl.date_n.get();
     });
}
```

Comment: can you give some more explanation on this one, I am having a problem understanding the concept because I am new to meteor,  for e.g. what do this.date_n = new ReactiveVar(); does? what is happening in the events section and what is happening in the helpers section?

Comment: This is all about ReactiveVar (you can google for it if you need more info) basically in 'onCreated' lifecycle event you want to create new reactive variable which will live on your template instance. Then in events part you can set the value for your reactive variable 'tmpl' here is the same as 'this' in the onCreated event. You will use here setter function 'set()'. Next in the helper section you can use 'get()' function to get the current value from your reactive variable. In the helper section you need to find template instance by Template.instance().

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **[Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session)** variable to store Template instance variables. It provides a global object on the client that you can use to store an arbitrary set of key-value pairs. Use it to store things like the currently selected item in a list. In your case, you could try something like this for your template (untested):

```
Template.pricing_report.events({
    'click #btn_report_filter': function() {
        var from_date = $("#datepicker1").val(),
            to_date = $("#datepicker2").val(),    
            from = new Date(from_date),    
            to = new Date(to_date);

        Session.set("to_date", to);
        Session.set("from_date", from);
    }
});

Template.pricing_report.helpers({

    'preportdata': function(){
        return price.find();
    },

    'preportdata_test': function() {
        return price.find({
            date: { 
                $gte: Session.get('to_date'),
                $lt:  Session.get('from_date')
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code but its not working, don't know why but Session.get('to_date') and Session.get('from_date') doesn't getting any value.